# Different log files in Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have a rails app and I want to be able to use different log files in each environment. So it won't be only `development.log` in development environment, there'll be multiple log files in it depending on the kinds of events that occur. How can I do that?

UDPATE:
In, say, development environment the log file where everything written into is `development.log`. I want to have multiple log files more in development environment along with `development.log`.

Comment: you want different log file names based on the environment or you mean you need to log diff things in diff events? be more clear

Comment: @uDaY, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Rails chooses log file automatically depending on the environment it runs in.

```
development => log/development.log
test => log/test.log
production => log/production.log
my_custom_env => log/my_custom_env.log
```

You can change the log file in specific environment like this:

In **config/environment.rb**

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(File.join(ENV['SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VAR'], "destination/filename.log"))
```